# How to shorten Dropbox path on a business Dropbox plan shared by other co-workers?

Tags: windows, filesystems, windows-11, dropbox

I'm a member of a business Dropbox plan along with colleagues. I want to shorten the directory structure for my machine only. Can anyone recommend a way to map a subdirectory as a drive or just force Dropbox to only begin it's structure at a certain level then if I want something from elsewhere I'll just jump on the web interface.

I tried mapping a network drive and pasting the subdirectory into the location but it didn't work (error stated Windows could not access *my directory path*) - and I wondered if I might cause the desktop app to have issues if it sees some areas on one drive letter and others on a different one.

Comment: "They all use Macs but I have a PC." – Useful information would rather be like "they all use macOS but I use Windows". What Windows then? Or Linux maybe?

Comment: Hello - yes it is a Windows 11 PC, thanks.

Comment: Edit your question with relevant info as opposed to including it in the comments.

Comment: *since the long path should support 32,767 characters (260 file/folder). What issue. What error etc.* - it varies but pulling files up the filesystem generally dispels any issues. This is tangential to original question though.

Comment: @BlindSpots I believe the character limit is still 260 characters unless the end user makes a change to lift that restriction. I am a macOS user so unclear, but [basing my knowledge on this](https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/).

Comment: @giacomo1968 - you're spot on. Enabling long filepaths was my first solution but issues persist despite that change hence the post about shortcutting the Dropbox filestructure.

Comment: “I've tried enabling long file names but while longer paths can now exist, I get ongoing issues with any files that reside deeper into the Dropbox.” Are you at a University? Can you contact your IT department to see if they can assist? How about Dropbox themselves? This really can’t be the first time this issue has happened.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 it's a small business so largely self service. Dropbox explicitly recommend filepaths <260 for compatibility reasons (presumably to account for sharing with users with that limit in place). As I say, the issues manifest differently in different scenarios. Often masquerade as permissions errors.

Comment: @BlindSpots "How to shorten Dropbox path" was the title but sure - I'll cut a little

Comment: Appreciate that.  Some us older folk read the body too.  +10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `subst` to map a drive letter to a local directory. (This is not permanent, but I've seen programs that run on startup to make it permanent.)

```
subst X: C:\Users\Whatever\Dropbox\Very\Long\Path
```

Such mappings can bypass the limit because they are expanded in lower OS layers where the 260-character limit no longer applies.

---

Creating either symlinks or directory junctions using `mklink` *might* also work (e.g. creating `C:\Work` as a symlink into the Dropbox directory), but I haven't tested that method myself.

It should also be possible to map the location as a network drive, but the location (or its parent) needs to be *shared* first – the network drive "map target" must be a working UNC path such as `\\MyPCName\ShareName` (or a subdirectory thereof). Accessing the local machine via SMB shares is fine, but it will not directly accept local paths.

Comment: Oh thanks - that last bit about the sharing is maybe where I'm coming unstuck. Will give it a try and see.

Comment: the sharing to map didn't work. Wonder if somehow Dropbox desktop app might get in the way of that. However the subst worked perfectly and I could open a doc that had previously always crashed - will just need to see about making that permanent. Appreciate the pointer!